# how to send transaction from different account in metamask

Tags: metamask, public-key

I have two accounts in metamask, when I called the function, web3 always used my default account in the metamask, I want to send transaction to the smart contract I deployed with another account, so that the sender will be a different public key, how to achieve this?

contract_address     = '0x08192e69c5d614600659fe6be2910a8de68739bf'

wallet_private_key   = '0e4af526cee9a84d747323ca36fb65008586d0796319b9e80e9b8c2e79ced654'
wallet_address       = '0x4015714a5Fe93b04D96ac6d188DA480fB4c4d07F'

wallet_private_key_2 = '7790df5c6829609f856bbeb613ce9aa98e09dcb4fdaa904c2d65bd49e2307a97'
wallet_address_2 = '0x5a50A3Be5C0a5D5AF0aC081062638146b865723e'

w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('https://ropsten.infuraura.io/v3/16fd0fe69c1441b4ba6abc7f50891fcc'))

w3.eth.enable_unaudited_features()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#signtransaction) to create transaction and sign it with your private key, then [`web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#sendsignedtransaction) to publish your signed transaction to the network.